# how to set text of titleForHeaderInSection to AlignmentCenter

Tags: iphone, ios

i  used  the  follow  code to set the title at the group tableview title header,but default the text is AlignmentLeft,how to AlignmentCenter?

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section==0){
        return NSLocalizedString(@"more_titlehead_one", nil);
    }else if (section==1){
        return NSLocalizedString(@"more_titlehead_two", nil);
    }else{
        return NSLocalizedString(@"more_titlehead_three", nil);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try like this,

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     UILabel * sectionHeader = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
     sectionHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     sectionHeader.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
     sectionHeader.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
     sectionHeader.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

     switch(section) {
        case 0:sectionHeader.text = @"TITLE ONE"; break;
        case 1:sectionHeader.text = @"TITLE TWO"; break;
        default:sectionHeader.text = @"TITLE OTHER"; break;
     }  
   return sectionHeader;
}
```

set some default height for Header,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewheightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     switch(section) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        default:return 20;
     }  
}
```

Comment: how to set the UIlabel sectionHeader width and height to the default value?

Comment: using this,- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewheightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{return HEIGHT;}

Answer (score 4):

Use the below method to set the UIView item for the header in each section:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerVw = [[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)] autorelease];
    headerVw.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"title_bg.png"]]; // set color of header

    UILabel *itemlbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 320, 20)];

    if(section==0){
        itemlbl.text = NSLocalizedString(@"more_titlehead_one", nil);
    }else if (section==1){
        itemlbl.text = NSLocalizedString(@"more_titlehead_two", nil);
    }else{
        itemlbl.text = NSLocalizedString(@"more_titlehead_three", nil);
    }
    itemlbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    itemlbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    itemlbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    itemlbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    [headerVw addSubview:itemlbl];
    [titlelbl release];
    return headerVw;
}
```

Best of luck

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple use `UILabel` with its Alignment **center**. in `viewForHeaderInSection`

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UILabel *lbl = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
    lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    lbl.text = @"Header Title";
    return lbl;
}
```