# Populate UITableView from JSON data

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview

I have JSON data

```
[{"id": 1,"Name": "Nodia","company": "WWW","position": "HR","email": "sss@www.com","number": "33","photo": "image1.png"}, {"id": 2,"Name": "Nona ","company": "SSS","position": "Head of Department","email": "aaaa@samsda.ge","number": "5496","photo": "image2.png"}, {"id": 3,"Name": "David","company": "DDD","position": "Director","email": "test@sasd.e","number": "574","photo": "image3.png"},....]|
```

I create a table view with value Name.

```
Tableviewcontroller.h :
     @interface CitiesViewController ()
        @property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *jsonArray
        @property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *citiesArray;
-(void)retrieveData;
```

---

```
Tableviewcontroller.m :
   @implementation CitiesViewController
        @synthesize 

citiesArray,jsonArray;

    #pragma mark -

    #pragma mark Class Methods

    -(void)retrieveData
    {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        citiesArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (int i= 0; i<jsonArray.count; i++)
        {
            NSString *cID = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
            NSString *cName = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
            NSString *cCompany = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"company"];
            NSString *cPosition = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"position"];
            NSString *cEmail = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"email"];

            NSString *cNumber = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"number"];
            NSString *cPhoto = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"photo"];

            NSURL *urlOne = [NSURL URLWithString:cPhoto];
       //     NSLog(@"%@",urlOne);
            NSData *photoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlOne];
            UIImage *imageOne = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:photoData];

            [citiesArray addObject:[[City alloc]initWithCityName:cName andCityState:cCompany andCityCountry:cEmail andCityPopulation:cPosition andCityID:cID andCityNumber:cNumber andCityPhoto: (UIImage *) imageOne]];

        }

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

       [self retrieveData];

    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
            return 1;
        }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
            return citiesArray.count;

    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Configure the cell...


        City *cityob;
        cityob=[citiesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text=cityob.employeeName;


        return cell;

    }
```

Everything works fine.Cell shows data. But the problem is that I can not set  title header for section and section index titles in TableView.and I want alphabetic header for section
Because the data is dynamic static solution to the problem is not suitable.
 [like in this tutriole](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/)

Thanks very much.forgive my bad English!

Comment: Though this is the Swift version of code, you should be using `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? { }` which is an extension of `UITableViewDelegate`. You can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15740781/3921490) for reference.

Comment: @amagain detail as possible?

Comment: @amagain - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

}   but I do not know how to implement

Answer (score 0):

As amagain already stated, you need to implement tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:. You currently only have one section and it is unclear what you want to show, but an example implementation would look something like this:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

NSString *sectionNameString = @"Current Jobs";
return sectionNameString;}
```

Typing this on my iPhone, but this is approximately how it would look. Use a string compare function *outside the scope of your class* like so:

```
NSInteger sortCitiesByName(City *city1, City *city2, void *context) {
NSString *name1 = [city1 name];
NSString *name2 = [city2 name];
return [name1 localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: name2];}
```

and then sort your array something like this:

```
citiesArray = [citiesArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:sortCitiesByName context:nil];
```

Comment: I want sorting array in alphabetic order

Comment: For that you would use something like this on your citiesArray:

- (NSArray<ObjectType> *)sortedArrayUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator;
or
- (NSArray<ObjectType> *)sortedArrayUsingFunction:(NSInteger (*)(ObjectType, ObjectType, void * __nullable))

Comment: and that it will give me?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
       return [citiesArray objectAtIndex:section];
    }
```

Please check this out and make suitable modifications.

Comment: may create a individual array for alphabet?i want alphabetic header for section